# Git remove commit from remote branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch, git-remote

I created a local repo with an initial commit and afterwards I committed all my work. I want to keep my clean history.

Someone else created the remote branch on Bitbucket (master and develop branch). He also did an 'initial commit'. I didn't yet connect to this remote branch.

What is the best way to remove the 'initial commit' on the remote branch and then push all my code to remote (started from my 'initial commit')?

Comment: How did someone else push to your repository unless you invited them to? But in any case, you can use `git push --mirror` to overwrite the remote with what you have locally.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is two branches with a single commit (with mostly no *meaningful* content) and only you have the second revision with the content, if you want to create the smallest possible fuss, I think you should keep the other branch from the other repo, assuming the other repo is the "official" one. How do you go about it? On your local repo, do this:

```
git remote add other-repo url-to-other-repo
git fetch --all
git checkout other-repo/other-branch
git cherry-pick my-branch # bring over your meaningful changes... assuming they are all in a single revision at the tip of the branch
# if you like it
git push other-repo HEAD:other-branch
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the commit-id and then run

```
git revert <commit-id>
```

This will create a new commit that will undo the previous commit. The history will contain the old and new commit

Or you can also delete the previous commit as

```
 git reset HEAD^ --hard
```